# Explain why this algorithm does not guarantee mutual exclusion

Tags: algorithm, concurrency, mutual-exclusion

Consider the following ‘busy waiting’ attempt for a mutual exclusion algorithm.
Explain why this does not guarantee mutual exclusion.  I can't figure out why it doesn't, to me it looks like it should can anyone explain why it doesn't?

```
/*Process0 */
while (flag[1]) do {/* nothing */}
flag[0] = true;
/*critical section */
flag[0] = false;

/*Process1 */
while (flag[0]) do {/* nothing */}
flag[1] = true;
/*critical section */
flag[1] = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because things you're apparently thinking of as atomic (i.e., inseperable) aren't anything of the sort.

Right now, you seem to assume that as soon as the `while` loop in one process exits, execution will continue through at least the entirety of the assignment to `flag[N]` without any context switches.

This simply isn't true. For the sake of argument, let's break each process into part A (the while loop) and B (the critical section). It's entirely possible to have a sequence like:

```
1A
2A
1B [for a while, then interrupted by context switch]
2B [for a while, then interrupted by context switch]
1B [resumes after context switch]
2B [resumes after context switch]
```

This is *exactly* the sort of code that works 99.9% of the time. You can probably test it like crazy for months on end, and it'll *seem* like it works perfectly--then you demo it in front of a customer, it crashes, burns, and destroys its surroundings. Then you send it back to the lab, and try though they will, they can't duplicate the problem.

Comment: `You can probably test it like crazy for months on end, and it'll seem like it works perfectly--then you demo it in front of a customer, it crashes, burns, and destroys its surroundings. Then you send it back to the lab, and try though they will, they can't duplicate the problem.`------ ha ha ha(ROFL)...

Answer (score 0):

Two things can happen here.

1. You can have two (or more) processes running concurrently. Either one may grab

   while (flag[1]) do {/* nothing */}
        // Both processes may see the flag cleared at the same time

   ```
    flag[0] = true;  // Two process set the flag
   ```
2. You could have a context switch

   while (flag[1]) do {/* nothing */}
        // Process gets blocked here

   ```
       // Some other process sets flag [0]

    flag[0] = true;  // Gets set for a second time
   ```